# PHP count lines in a file.php that's inside a .zip archive

Tags: php, zip

I have a file.php inside a .zip archive. In this example my file has 10 lines of code in it. How do i count those lines using php?(i can count them for files outside that .zip but i can't figure out how to count those lines for files inside that zip :().

Thank you! :D

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting a file handler using `getStream();` method that's already built in PHP ZipArchive class. Your code will look something like this:

```
$lines = 0;
$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open('path/to/your/archive.zip')) { //make sure you edit this
    $fp = $z->getStream('file.php'); //and this according to your file names and path/s
    if(!$fp) exit("Couldn't find your file.");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $line = fgets($fp);
        $lines++;
    }
    fclose($fp);
    echo $lines; //Total lines counter
}
```

Comment: Thank youuuuu so much! <3 it worked! :D thank you thank you thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer can be extract the contents of zip file count out the lines (you already know) remove the files.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('/path/');
    $zip->close();
    // read lines then delete extracted files using unlink()
 } else {
     echo 'ERROR!';
 }
```

Comment: Its just a possible answer not the perfect solution for the case!

Comment: Hei Arti! Thank you for your answer! I still want to try to get the lines number without extracting a file, but thank you for your time and idea! :D